How to install managed dependency for example a Powershell module in Powershell based azure functions?
In Azure function app, we are able to install Az modules as default as it mentions in the requiremnts.psd1 file as shown in the below image by uncommenting , it will install the Az module
enter image description here
By following the same process we are trying to install Microsoft.graph modules in the function app to use Microsoft graph commands in the scripts and followed the same process by mentioning it in the requirements.psd1 file as shown in the below image
enter image description here
but it fails
tried different combinations in requirements .psd1 file as shown below
for example
@{
# For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 

# To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.

Az = '11.*'

Microsoft.Graph = '2.15.0'

}
@{
# For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 

# To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.

'Microsoft.Graph' = '2.15.0'

}
but it either fails or timeouts as shown below
enter image description here
enter image description here
and the only working one which we found is to upload the files manually into D:\home\site\wwwroot\Modules of the function and the commands worked as expected.
But the problem we face is to create a function app with Microsoft graph modules loaded automatically similar to how we can install Az modules in the function app by changing the contents of requirements.psd1 file instead of manually adding the function app by uploading the files.
**Can anyone please suggest why it does not install other modules but installs Az modules when mentioned in requirements.psd1 file but only works by uploading manually.**Thank You

Try installing individual modules that are available within Microsoft.Graph, such as below for example:
'Microsoft.Graph.Groups' = '1.'
'Microsoft.Graph.Users' = '1.'
That worked for me, if I recall correctly I tried exactly the same thing you are trying with installing the whole of Microsoft.Graph and it would just not install.
